# Need to get number of Items used in last 3 days as well as used items in last year

Tags: sql

**I have the query where I can fetch last 3 days records perfectly**

```
Select ProductID, Description, Count(productID) AS [Last 3 days item count]

From VIEW_ItemsUsed

Where DateUsed >= Getdate()-3

Group by ProductID
```

**But when I include the condition for fetching the number of items used in last year in the same query, getting invalid data**

```
Select ProductID, Description, Count(productID) AS [Last 3 days item count], Count(ProductID) AS [Last Year Item counts]

From VIEW_ItemsUsed

Where DateUsed >= Getdate()-3
      AND DateUsed >= Getdate()-365

Group by ProductID
```

Please provide me the solution

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and date/time functions are quite vendor specific). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: With WHERE you are actually filtering data, so for this to work you will have to combine 2 queries with 2 where statements one for 3 days another for 1 year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
Select ProductID, Description,
       sum(case when dateUsed >= getdate() - 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_3days,
       sum(case when dateUsed >= getdate() - 365 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_365days
From VIEW_ItemsUsed
Where DateUsed >= Getdate() - 365
Group by ProductID, Description;
```